# Play video from webserver

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Greeting,
I'm creating a video player with silverlight 4 and C#. the player is working fine when I set the path for the target folder using this line of code.

```
string FolderPath = this.Context.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath(@"~\Video\");
```

Now I want to place in C:\inetpub\wwwroot and I want to use the IP address of my IIS instead of the folder place.
please advice how to modify this line of code to target my IIS.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make sure things are set up to stream via http v.s. file. This resource might help.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/05/06/streaming-media-in-silverlight.aspx